# How to insert data in Asp.net page when the table has an identity column

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server-2008

I'm getting error when I'm inserting data in database into a table with an `identity` specification.

**SQL**

```
string query = "insert into student values('"+txtname.Text+"','"+name_image+"','"+txtage.Text+"','"+txtaddress.Text+‌​"')";
```

Error is

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: please insert your `Table Structure` and 1Insert Data Code1 here

Comment: Please provide you query here....

Comment: string query = "insert into student values('"+txtname.Text+"','"+name_image+"','"+txtage.Text+"','"+txtaddress.Text+"')";

Comment: In this code the first column id have a auto increment propertie which is not include in a Query

Comment: Please read this article on Parametized SQL: http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/ . It won't answer your question but will protect your website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont Try to Fill the auto-Increment column. Provides the column value other than auto-increment column.

suppose Column-1 is Auto-incremented then the query will be

```
Insert into tableName(Column-2,column-3,..) Values(val-2,val-3,..);
```

Leave the auto increment column

Comment: string query = "insert into student values('"+txtname.Text+"','"+**name_image**+"','"+txtage.Text+"','"+txtaddress.Text+‌​"')";     Give here image url and defne name_Image to nvarchar

Comment: I'm not including auto increment column but still getting error

Comment: please provide your table structure

Comment: Error-Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition. getting when I'm run the program name_image is working in my other project same code but another table whose column not have a auto increment propertie

Answer (score 3):

You should get in the habit of *always* specifying the explicit list of columns you want to insert values into - that way, you can omit the `identity` column and prevent this error:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Student(Col1, Col2, ...., ColN)
VALUES(Val1, Val2, ...., ValN)
```

Just saying `INSERT INTO dbo.Students VALUES(...)` means you have to provide a value for **every** column - including the `identity` column - which you cannot provide a value for!